# How to get the last and first element from a rust iterator

Tags: rust

This is part of the [Day 1 of Advent of Code 2023](https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/1). I would like to extract the digit, get the first and last character, and convert back to integer. Here is the working version.

```
fn main() {
    let line = "treb7uchet";

    // Find all the digit
    let v: String = line
        .chars()
        // Filter the numeric character
        .filter(|c| c.is_numeric() )
        // Only filter the first element
        // .enumerate()
        // .filter(|&(i, _)| i == 0)
        // .map(|(_, e)| e)
        .collect::<String>();

    // println!("{}", v);

    // Get the first and the last digit, convert into number
    let my_int: i32 = format!("{}{}", v.chars().nth(0).unwrap(), v.chars().last().unwrap())
        .parse()
        .unwrap();

    println!("{}", my_int);
}

Ans: 77
```

This snippet already work but I would wonder if I could get everything running on 1 line of code instead of 2. I tried the `enumerate` (commented code) but it could only `filter` the first item (by knowing its index). I would like to know how could I filter the last item as well. Or are there any way that I can extract the last and first element in the iterator?

Thanks in advance.

Please feel free to test it in [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c46e04a9eb75db706ff198d98c5bf5ae).

Comment: Rather than trying to find a single-line solution, you could instead do away with collecting the iterator into a `String`, instead assigning it to a (mutable) binding upon which you'd then call `.next()` and `.next_back()` in subsequent statements.  Saves on the needless allocation.

Comment: @eggyal Thanks. The reason why I want to do it one line is because the `line` variable in the example is only one line. But the actual input is multiple lines. And it would like to get the `sum` of it. Thus I want to do the one line solution is because don't want to write a for loop and sum the for loop. If I can get it one line then I can add the `sum()` at the very end.

Comment: Okay, so you have an iterator whose items are similar to `line` above?  And then you `.map()` that iterator to numbers which you then `.sum()`?  The mapping function can still involve multiple statements though (if using a lambda, just place the body in `{}` braces).

Comment: @eggyal 

I found a solution in one line and thats what I want to achieve.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/timvisee/advent-of-code-2023/master/day01a/src/main.rs

But still, want to understand why way (getting all numeric char out of the string, get the fisrt and last) would work

Comment: That solution (like the second part of your original post) creates two iterators: one to obtain the first digit and the other to obtain the last one.  I don't think there's any particularly obvious or ergonomic way to obtain both from a single iterator in a single expression.

Comment: The one-line code in the link doesn't appear to be performant, since it just embedded an inefficient closure into a single line of code. `Collect` would allocate memory so you should also avoid it as possible, as eggyal suggested.

Comment: @xcwang: the closure seems pretty optimal to my cursory glance, albeit it assumes the input is ASCII.  Why do you say the closure is inefficient ?

Comment: @eggyal I am not trying to copy but I would try to write the code after I think through. I didn't think his way is performant (so as my solution). So I would like to ask if I want to go my way (find out the numeric character, get the first and last item, combine that two character, convert it to integer and then sum it up). I would like to get everything in a chained fashion. But currently I can filter the numeric char but not sure how to filter the last and first element in a chained fashion (so called one line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the task has just short strings and even less digits, we can afford the O(n) to run over all digits. ;-)

The trick here is to use an iterator method that maintains a state, and to use this state to save the first digit. The initial state is encoded by a specific value and triggers the doubling for the case of a single digit.

This first idea keeps the `char` nature of the digits.

```rust
fn main() {
    let lines = ["1abc2", "pqr3stu8vwx", "a1b2c3d4e5f", "treb7uchet"];
    for line in lines {
        println!(
            "{}",
            String::from_iter(
                line.chars()
                    .filter(|c| c.is_numeric())
                    .fold(['_', '_'], |acc, c| if acc[0] == '_' {
                        [c, c]
                    } else {
                        [acc[0], c]
                    })
                    .iter()
            )
        );
    }
}
```

This second idea takes advantage of `to_digit()` and is even simpler.

```rust
fn main() {
    let lines = ["1abc2", "pqr3stu8vwx", "a1b2c3d4e5f", "treb7uchet"];
    for line in lines {
        println!(
            "{}",
            line.chars()
                .filter_map(|c| c.to_digit(10))
                .fold(100, |acc, d| if acc > 99 {
                    11 * d
                } else {
                    acc - acc % 10 + d
                })
        );
    }
}
```

The last simple step to sum all two-digit numbers is left as an exercise and not hard.

Comment: Thanks. The code works. Let me take a look at how `fold` works.

Answer (score 2):

There's a far simpler, zero-copy solution.

[`char::to_digit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.to_digit) returns an `Option` which will be `Some` with the digit as a `u32` if the character is a valid digit.  We can exploit this with `filter_map` to produce an iterator of characters in a string that are digits, converted to `u32`:

```
let mut digits = line.chars().filter_map(|c| c.to_digit(10));
```

We can take from both ends since `Chars` is a `DoubleEndedIterator`.  However, since the first and last characters can be the same character in the string, we can't just call `next` and then `next_back`, because `next_back` will return `None` when the string contains a single digit.

We can get around this by storing the first digit and then using it as the default value in the case that `next_back` returns `None`.

```
let first = digits.next().unwrap();
let last = digits.next_back().unwrap_or(first);
```

To produce the number for a line, we just take 10 times the first digit and add it to the last digit:

```
first * 10 + last
```

Note that nowhere in this code do we allocate a `String` and then parse it!  We're just manipulating numbers; there are zero heap allocations.

We can combine this with iteration over multiple lines to produce a very fast and easy to understand solution:

```
lines
    .lines()
    .map(|line| {
        let mut digits = line.chars().filter_map(|c| c.to_digit(10));

        let first = digits.next().unwrap();
        let last = digits.next_back().unwrap_or(first);

        first * 10 + last
    })
    .sum();
```

IMO this is way more readable than a single-line mapping function.

Now, if you *really want a single line* even though it will be harder to read then you can achieve that, though note that it repeats the code that creates the iterator:

```
line.chars().filter_map(|c| c.to_digit(10)).next().unwrap() * 10 + line.chars().filter_map(|c| c.to_digit(10)).next_back().unwrap()
```

This line is long enough that rustfmt wants to wrap it onto multiple lines -- even more lines than the prior approach I give.

Technically you can write any program as a one-liner, but there is a very good reason we don't do that, so I would strongly urge you to reconsider your goal of a one-liner solution.

Comment: Thanks. I guess more or less like it. A restructure of the code so that it can be chained along. Just one question, is it possible that if I can filter the last and first element on the character level (commented code on the question) using filter or other function?

Comment: @Winston Probably yes, but the request is a bit ambiguous. Can you clarify what you mean by providing input and the expected output?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In your code you split the thing in line and process each line. In my code (in the first post), I split the whole thing into character. What I think is to filter out the character that is numeric (which the `filter` work). I would get back a char array that only contains numeric char. Then I would like to do the next filtering process to get only the first and last char in the char array. And that's the part that I don't know how to proceed. So there is comment code that can get the first char (`enum`,`filter`,`map`) but I am not sure how to get the end of the char array

Comment: I think what I really want is not the solution (the code is already working). But I want to write it in a one line way. But I got stuck then I have to split the code into two parts/lines. I would rather want to learn how could I get the first and last item from the char array than a solution. Really thanks because I learn the new `filter_map` =)

Comment: @Winston You could do this with `fold` but with some performance loss.

Comment: Thanks although performance is not in my priority list, I would wonder why this method would lead to performance loss

Comment: @Winston Because it must iterate over every character, while scanning from the two ends will stop when it finds a digit. For strings where the first and last digits have at least one character between them, scanning from the ends will have to test fewer characters because it can skip the ones in the middle; fold will not be able to skip them. However, `lines()` already will look at each character, so if you can reduce the entire operation to a _single_ fold that also computes the sum, then, theoretically, you can get an increase in performance, but the code will be substantially more complex.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Just wonder if performance is an issue, would it be faster if I use `regex` to filter all digit number from the whole thing (not line-by-line, then char-by-char) first. Coz I think checking char-by-char would be slow...

Comment: @Winston A regex will almost certainly be slower. It's going to check every character anyway, and it's a general-purpose solution which means it's not optimized for this particular case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I really didn't have optimization on my head. I am just learning rust by using AOC. I found that Python version took 3 lines of code while the rust version took me hours. I am not sure what is being missed.

Comment: @Winston Rust is very different from many other languages. It has algebraic data types (enum) and traits, but also isn't an OOP language. It's very possible that you're approaching Rust with the mindset of another language (e.g. Python). This is a natural way to learn new things, so you're not doing anything wrong, but bringing baggage from other languages to Rust will make it much harder to learn the Rust way of doing things. In particular, traits are _incredibly_ powerful, and it took me months of using Rust daily before I really grasped how to use them effectively.

Comment: Thanks. I wrote C/C++. Hope it would be useful too. It seems to me that rust is more functional programming than C but getting the data type correct is a bit hard. For example now I would like to create a string lookup table in rust. Online suggest that I should use HashMap but HashMap is dynamic in nature but I am not sure how to find it's static lookup table alternative. Sometimes it seems to me that doing the same thing in C would be easier than rust hahaha. Maybe this is a skill issue.

Comment: @Winston Keep learning Rust, and your current mind on programming, I guess, would finally be regulated to the right track some day.

Comment: @Winston `HashMap` is fine for static lookups. You can also use `match` in many cases. Depending on how many keys you have, one might be more efficient than the other.